# Getting error RAZORGENERATE : error RZ3008 creating Blazor ComponenBase

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

Upgraded to Preview9.

But getting this error when I try to separate View and Model, any ideas?

> RAZORGENERATE : error RZ3008: Tag helpers cannot target tag name
>   '.ViewCustomerModel' because it contains a '<'
>   character.

```
public class ViewCustomerModel: ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    protected IDataService Data {get;set;}

    [Parameter] 
    public Guid CustomerId {get;set;}
    public Customer Customer {get;set;}

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() 
    {
        await Load();
    }

    private async Task Cancel() => await Load();

    private async Task Load()
    {
        Customer = await Data.Load<Customer>(CustomerId);
    }

    private async Task Save(EditContext editContext)
    {
        if (editContext.Validate())
        {
            await Data.Save<Customer>(Customer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a generated file somewhere under the `obj` folder so you can see what the literal output is? You get them for. razor files, wondering if there might be one for CS files when they inherit ComponentBase?

Comment: @PeterMorris I think it gets compiled into the assembly, only the razor pages have the compiled g.cs files.

Comment: Can you show the mark-up where you are trying to use this component?

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter, MSFT showed me the errors in my ways, I will post an answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per MSFT https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13881

You require a namespace always, wrapping the class in a namespace is required.